# javascript change image on hover (inline)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

```
function roll_over(img_name, img_src) {
document[img_name].src = img_src;
}

<a href="..."
onmouseover="roll_over('but100', '...')"
onmouseout="roll_over('but100', '...')">
<img src="..." name="but100" />
</a>
```

I use this code to display a tshirt and display a zoomed image on mouse hover.
I want to dynamically resize the onmouseover image. The images are 190x190px but i want them to be displayed in 160x160px without changing the code too much. What's the best way ?

Comment: Just add image `width='160px'` and `height='160px'` and change height width of that one on hover

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a JS for this just ordinary css is enough.

```
img:hover{
   width:160px;
   height:160px;
}

img{
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/srzq7/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use reduced height and width of image in HTML. And JS/JQuery for resize:

```
$('#imageId').attr('height', 190).attr('width', 190);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is let the img be 100% of a href size:

```
a:hover {
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
}

img { 
    width: 100%; 
    height:100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript this can be done as

Html

```
<a onmouseover="roll_over(this,true)" onmouseout="roll_over(this,false)">
<img src="http://www.anotherlogosite.com/images/loghi/set01/engine_positivo_preview.jpg"
```

/>

Javascript

```
function roll_over(ctrl,isMouseOver)
{
    var height,width;
    if(isMouseOver)
    {
        height="190px";
        width="190px";
    }
    else{
        height="160px";
        width="160px";
    }
    $(ctrl).find("img").css({"width":width,"height":height});
}
```

Or by css as

```
img
{
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
}

img:hover
{
    width:190px;
    height:190px;
}
```

link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WMpMm/)

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/48W3j/)